# Flutter How to visualize nested maps from Firebase

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-futurebuilder

Im working on a project that it has nested maps in Firebase.

First of all here is Firebase document screenshot:
[image]

And this one is my how to fetch this document function to my model:

```
Future<StaffListModel> personelleriGetir(String id) async {
    try {
      var document = await _firestore
          .collection('path')
          .doc(id)
          .collection('path)
          .doc('staffs')
          .get();
      Map<String, dynamic>? documentData = document.data();
      print(documentData);
      return StaffListModel.fromMap(documentData ?? {});
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar('Error', e.code);
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

When I print documentData variable it returns perfectly(at least, thats what im thinking).

```
{staffList: [{user1: {Admin: {permission1: true, permission2: true}}}, {user2: {Admin: {permission1: true, permission2: true}}}]}
```

So here is my `StaffListModel` class:

```
class StaffListModel {
  List<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, bool>>>>? staffs;
  StaffListModel({
    this.staffs,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'staffs': staffs,
    };
  }

  factory StaffListModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return StaffListModel(
      staffs: map['staffs'] != null
          ? List<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, bool>>>>.from(map['staffs']
              ?.map((x) => Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, bool>>>.from(x)))
          : null,
    );
  }
}
```

Before if you ask what is this section " `map['staffs']` ", I will say it is my Firebase Document's name.

Btw, I am using `Riverpod FutureBuilder` but it doesn't matter. I want to show this model in `listViewBuilder.`

I tried everything i know but i never show it up in ui.
Here is what i tried:

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: staffFuture.when(
                  data: ((data) => ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 1,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Text(data.staffs[index][]. toString());
                        },
                      )),
                  error: (error, s) => Text('Error'),
                  loading: () => const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      )),
            ),
```

Thanks from now.

Comment: If you want help with why it doesn't show up in the UI, you should probably share the code for the UI. Or, if the error is that it's not converting to `StaffListModel`, you should probably state that, cause with what you have right now, there's no telling what's going wrong.

Comment: You're right. I added it inside question. Thanks.